# combining json details with other data in repeat region

Tags: php, json

I have a MySQLi query as follows...

```
SELECT
VENDORS.ID, VENDORS.SECTION, VENDORS.`NAME`, VENDORS.IMAGE, VENDORS.LOGO, VENDORS.WEBSITE, VENDORS.OTHER_IMAGES
FROM VENDORS
```

The OTHER_IMAGES field holds json data on a bunch of images related to each query, and the other fields are simple text fields.

I have created the following code that is showing the json images correctly, and uses a php repeat region to cycle through and extract all the data in the table.

How can I include the other data from the query in the repeat region, specifically I want to include the field NAME under each image (each json has approx 8 images, all would have the same NAME field attached)

Is this possible?

```
<?php
while(!$Recordset1->atEnd()) {
?>

<?php 
    $someJSON = $Recordset1->getColumnVal("OTHER_IMAGES");

    $someArray = json_decode($someJSON, true);

    foreach ($someArray as $key => $value) {
        echo 
            "<div class=\"ms-slide\" data-delay=\"3\" 
            data-fill-mode=\"fill\">
            <img src=\"pics/".$value["name"]." title=\"Bridal Images\" 
            data-src=\"pics/".$value["name"]."\" />
            </div>";
    }
?>

<?php
      $Recordset1->moveNext();
}
$Recordset1->moveFirst(); //return RS to first record
?>
```

Raw json...

```
[
   {"name":"..\/pics\/MBMR1_1dx7exnj.jpg",
    "usrName":"MBMR1.jpg",
    "size":32153,
    "type":"image\/jpeg",
    "thumbnail":"..\/pics\/thMBMR1_p43g5udy.jpg",
    "thumbnail_type":"image\/jpeg",
    "thumbnail_size":6008,
    "searchStr":"MBMR1.jpg,!MBMR5.jpg,!MBMR6.jpg,!MBMR2.jpg,!MBMR8.jpg,!MBMR7.jpg,!MBMR9.jpg,!MBMR4.jpg,!MBMR3.jpg,!MBMR10.jpg,!:sStrEnd"},
```

Additional code required to add to repeat region...

```
<div class="ms-info">
        <h3 style="font-weight: 300; color: #222222; text-align: center;">
          <?php echo($Recordset1->getColumnVal("NAME")); ?>
        </h3>

      </div>
```

Comment: An example of the Raw JSON held in `OTHER_IMAGES` would be useful

Comment: absolutely, I added to the bottom of the oroiginal question, hope that helps

Comment: Formatting it so its readable is also normally very useful

Comment: Tell you what, you add some HTML to show what you mean by ___in the repeat region___ to the code and I will tell you how to add the data to it

Comment: thank you I appreciate it, I have added what I would add if it was a non-json repeat region :)